# Asyncio task raises CancelledError despite being awaited

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm creating a program to better understand producer-consumer flow and using queues.

I keep getting `asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError` at the end of the coroutine even though to my understanding everything is correctly awaited and all the queues are properly used and joined.

I can't find the culprit and I've been testing this for quite a bit. Maybe someone else can see what I sadly cannot.

The flow goes like this:

1. Open new session, create one queue for handling API requests and a second queue for API responses.
2. Put all requests on `request_queue`
3. Create 5 `api_workers` to work on the requests from one queue, produce responses and put them on the other queue
4. Create a single `profile_worker` that consumes the responses
5. Wait for all requests to be processed
6. Cancel the `request_workers`
7. Wait for all the responses to be processed
8. Cancel the `profile_worker`
9. Wait for `request_workers` to finish (`gather` them all)
10. Wait for `profile_worker` to finish

```py
async def get_profiles():
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        request_queue = asyncio.Queue()
        profile_queue = asyncio.Queue()
        profiles = list()

        for request in make_get_profile_requests(names, token):
            await request_queue.put(request)

        api_workers = [asyncio.create_task(
            api_response_producer(session,
                                  request_queue, profile_queue))
            for _ in range(0, 5)]

        profile_worker = asyncio.create_task(
            profile_producer(profile_queue, profiles))

        await request_queue.join()
        for worker in api_workers:
            worker.cancel()
        await profile_queue.join()
        profile_worker.cancel()

        await asyncio.gather(*api_workers, return_exceptions=True)
        await profile_worker        
        return profiles
```

The 5 `api_workers` take in requests from `request_queue` and put responses in `profile_queue`.

```py
async def api_response_producer(session: ClientSession,
                                queue_in: Queue, queue_out: Queue):
    while True:
        request: Request = await queue_in.get()
        print('Working on: {} -> {}'.format(
            request.params["nick"], request.params["command"]))
        if request.method == Request.GET:
            async with session.get(
                get_api_server(), params=request.params) as response:
                response.raise_for_status()
                await queue_out.put(await response.json(
                    content_type=None))
                queue_in.task_done()
                print('Response ready: {} -> {}'.format(
                    request.params["nick"], request.params["command"]))
```

The `profile_worker` takes 4 recent responses and creates a `Profile` instance for each run.

```py
async def profile_producer(queue_in: Queue, profile_list: list):
   
    while True:
        profile = await queue_in.get()
        print(f"Received profile JSON: {profile}")
        queue_in.task_done()
        friends = await queue_in.get()
        print(f"Received friends JSON: {friends}")
        queue_in.task_done()
        photos = await queue_in.get()
        print(f"Received photos JSON: {photos}")
        queue_in.task_done()
        videos = await queue_in.get()
        print(f"Received videos JSON: {videos}")
        queue_in.task_done()

        print(f"Creating profile: {profile}")
        #profile_list.append(Profile(profile, friends, photos, videos))
        print(f"New profile ready: {profile}")
```

And to run this I use:

```py
profiles = asyncio.run(get_profiles())
```

**edit:*
The culprit was that `asyncio.gather()` for `request_workers` had the parameter `return_exceptions=True` and it handled the `CancelledError` for each of the workers.

The `profile_worker`'s exception on the other hand was not being handled.

Here's the fix - move `await profile_worker` to the `gather` list:

```py
await asyncio.gather(*api_workers, profile_worker,
                     return_exceptions=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading more about how `asyncio.gather()` handles task cancellation and how tasks raise the `CancelledError` that has to be handled if the task is simply awaited, I figured it out:

1. Move `profile_worker` to the `gather` task list and add exception handling

```py
await asyncio.gather(*api_workers, profile_worker,
                     return_exceptions=True)
```

2. Remove awaiting for the `profile_worker`

```py
await profile_worker
```